# Make Excel visible when closing userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have a button in an Excel worksheet that opens a userform when clicked. It also hides the worksheet, making it so you can only see the userform. Here's what I have to make that happen. This works fine.

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Application.Visible = False
    frmDataColl.Show
End Sub
```

Then I have this code that isn't working the way I want it to. Upon clicking the X to close the userform, I want the userform to close and also make Excel visible again. But this only closes the userform. It doesn't bring the workbook back into view.

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
    Application.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
     Debug.Print "Flag01" 
   Application.Visible = True`

Add a debug print statement to make sure you are executing the statement inside the if condition

Comment: In my test , it works well.

Comment: Adding that statement doesn't seem to be doing anything for me.

Comment: @Robby is noting gets printed on 'Immediate window'?

Comment: I don't see the immediate window, and I'm guessing that's because Excel is hidden.

Comment: The immediate window is in the VBE (Ctrl+G), has nothing to do with Excel being hidden.

Comment: enable Immediate window from your VBA editor... View>Immediate Window.

and you can terminate your hidden excel process from Task manager and reopen it for debugging.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine here. The only problem I'm seeing is that you're working off the form's default instance instead of treating it as an object, and that can (and usually does) lead to bugs. Change `Button2_Click` to do `With New frmDataCol1` and `.Show` instead, and change your `QueryClose` implementation to `Hide` the form instance given a `vbFormControlMenu` close mode; that way you'll take control of the object's lifetime ("X" button *destroys* the object by default). Also, follow [jkpieterse's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46058165/1188513).

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the Queryclose event and change your code to:

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Application.Visible = False
    frmDataColl.Show
    Application.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This. A form has no business controlling application visibility, **especially** if it didn't set it to `False` in the first place. I'd go one step further and use an instance of the form rather than do what all beginners do and work with a stateful default instance. `New` it up, it's an object! ...and *do* handle `QueryClose` - to *prevent* the form instance from self-destructing!

Comment: This works, but in addition to bringing back the workbook, it's creating another empty instance of Excel. Like there's a new Excel window, but a workbook isn't open in it.

Comment: Mat: I was trying to make things simpler. I agree treating the form as an object and instantiating it properly is the best way to do things.

Answer (score 1):

The form has no business knowing about `Application.Visible` state. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46058165/1188513) shows, `Button2` set it to `False`, it's `Button2`'s job to set it back to `True`.

Your code works perfectly fine here - the problem is likely in code you haven't posted. Keep procedures' responsibilities well defined and you won't have these issues.

Another common trap you've fallen into (as did the other answer), is to work with a stateful *default instance*. Forms are objects - treat them as such!

```
Application.Visible = False
With New frmDataCol1
    .Show
    ' here you still have access to the form's state!
End With
Application.Visible = True
```

Now, if you *don't* handle `QueryClose`, that red "X" button effectively **destroys the object** and, normally, you absolutely don't want that.

What you want, is to control the object's lifetime yourself - that's what you have that `With` block for!

So you *do* handle `QueryClose`, but only to say "*Hide* the form instance, don't *destroy* it!" - like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        Me.Hide
    End If
End Sub
```

That way when your dialog gets closed, the calling code can still access the public state and act accordingly. If you worked off the *default instance*, letting `QueryClose` destroy the instance causes the state to be lost. And since it's a *default instance*, a brand new one gets created as soon as you query that state, making the bug extremely difficult to find... if you don't know how objects with a default instance work.